# Unable to start a django server in my computer

Tags: django

I exported the path of my django project by

```
$ export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=/Users/masi/Documents/Test/djangobook/ch3.settings
```

I run unsuccessfully

```
$ django-admin.py runserver 
Error: Could not import settings '/Users/masi/Documents/Test/djangobook/ch3.settings' (Is it on sys.path? Does it have syntax errors?): Import by filename is not supported.
```

**How can you start Django server without the error message?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `$DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` should just be set to `ch3.settings`. Just make sure that the `ch3` app is in your `$PYTHONPATH`, too.

For example, if your app is at `/Users/masi/Documents/Test/djangobook/`, then set `$DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` to `ch3.settings`, and make sure your `$PYTHONPATH` includes `/Users/masi/Documents/Test/djangobook`.

```
$ export PYTHONPATH=/Users/masi/Documents/Test/djangobook/
$ export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=ch3.settings
```

Comment: @mipadi: I tried to make the PATHs permanent unsuccessfully by putting the codes to my .bashrc. I tried the code with and without ' ' for the PATH.

Comment: If you're using OS X, note that the PATH variable should be set in ~/.bash_profile

Comment: @Jarret: Thank you! The problem is now solved. I had a typo in my PATH.

Answer (score 1):

From the django docs on [django-admin.py and manage.py](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#ref-django-admin):

> django-admin.py is Django’s command-line utility for administrative tasks.
>
> In addition, manage.py is automatically created in each Django project. manage.py is a thin wrapper around django-admin.py that takes care of two things for you before delegating to django-admin.py:
>
> - It puts your project’s package on sys.path.
> - It sets the `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` environment variable so that it points to your project’s settings.py file.
>
> Generally, when working on a single Django project, it’s easier to use manage.py

So, if your directory structure looks like:

```
djangobook/
    ch3/
        settings.py
```

Do the following and you can ignore all DJANGO environment variables (unless you have some really weird install):

```
$ cd /Users/masi/Documents/Test/djangobook/ch3/
$ python manage.py runserver
```

Comment: Sounds like the python you're running has no django in its site-packages or path. How many copies of python do you have installed on your system? What happens if you change into the ch3/ directory, run the python interpreter (type: python) and type `import django`?

Answer (score 1):

For those that come across the same error, when trying to run something similar:

```
python manage.py runserver --settings=settings_dev
```

When the settings file is within an app directory, like so:

```
mysite/
  settings.py
  settings_dev.py
requirements.txt
manage.py
```

You don't have to specify `$PYTHONPATH` (at least not four years on) you just need to make sure your `--settings` value contains the folder name — you also need to use dot notation, slashes will not do.

```
python manage.py runserver --settings=mysite.settings_dev
```

It is the same story when exporting a `$DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` value:

```
export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=mysite.settings_dev
```

Might save someone else the time that I lost working that out.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try `manage.py`.

From your project directory, run

> `$ python manage.py runserver`

Even though it's just a wrapper, `manage.py` always works for me while `django-admin.py` doesn't. Obviously we're both doing something wrong (I just got started with Django), but this should get you going at least.