# Unable to find the Python module execute_manager in django.core.management

Tags: django

**Problem:** to find the Python module **execute_manager** in the class django.core.management.

The question is related to [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/744993/unable-to-start-a-django-server-in-my-computer/745014#745014) of mine.

I am trying to start my server by

```
python manage.py runserver
```

The command is dependent on **manage.py**.
The file imports the module **execute_manager** from the class django.core.management as follows

```
from django.core.management import execute_manager
```

I have tried to find the source code of the module unsuccessfully in the django installation folder by

```
$find . | grep exe
./django/core/management/commands/sqlindexes.py
```

Similarly, I get the following results by ack.

```
django/conf/project_template/manage.py
2:from django.core.management import execute_manager
11:    execute_manager(settings)

django/core/management/__init__.py
333:def execute_manager(settings_mod, argv=None):

examples/manage.py
2:from django.core.management import execute_manager
11:    execute_manager(settings)
```

**How can you find the source code of the module execute_manager** in the class django.core.management?

Comment: When you find yourself doing this, you need to ask yourself if this is the intended way of getting your server started. You shouldn't worry about this and make sure your python and django paths are set correctly. This is ignoring the actual problem.

Comment: @Paolo: I agree with you. However, I want to know how my code works. This allows me to locate bugs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`execute_manager` is a function, not a module, defined in the `__init__.py` file in the `django.core.management` package.  That is why your grep failed to find it.

Your ack found it with this result that you pasted:

```
django/core/management/__init__.py
333:def execute_manager(settings_mod, argv=None):
```

Comment: `>> import django`, `>>django.__file__` for location of django files.

Answer (score 2):

It's in the file `$PYTHON_SITE_PACKAGES/django/core/management/__init__.py`. `execute_manager` is a function, not a module, and the code for the `django.core.management` module is found in `django/core/management/__init__.py`, since `django.core.management` is also a package.